# Is it possible to express settings in VS Code's settings.json where each dot-separated part of a setting name gets its own "nested JSON object"?

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code

I am trying to understand the structure of the Visual Studio Code settings.json file. As I can see, there are multiple settings that appear to be JSON objects but are set separately. Take the following for example:

```json
  "javascript.autoClosingTags": true,
  "javascript.suggest.autoImports": true,
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
```

Now I am wondering if it is possible to turn this into something like the following:

```json
"javascript": {
    "autoClosingTags": true,
    "suggest": {
        "autoImports": true,
    }
    "updateImportsOnFileMove": {
        "enabled": "always"
    }
}
```

I have tried it with one or two settings but did not see an immediate difference which leads me to believe that this is indeed possible. On the other hand, I did get a few other seemingly unrelated errors, including failure of settings sync for me which has left me unconvinced.

Now I know this is possible for per-language settings like the following:

```json
  "[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": false
  },
```

But can we do that for `editor` key for example:

```json
 "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": false,
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file",
  "editor.formatOnType": false,
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity- why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DavePile Largely just experimenting and personal preference. I like the tree-like structure of JSON. This is definitely not a blocker.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, and the VS Code team considers it out of scope. Ex. See [Nested json settings #173303](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173303) (there are probably more issue tickets where this has been asked about, but they just elude my search queries).